# Using InsertionMode.Replace to replace current page after form submit with MVC 4 and jQuery Mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a site using jQuery Mobile. One of the pages is a partial view `<div id="page13">` which has a simple form to be sent to server that is set up using Ajax.BeginForm. The action method at the server updates a value in the database.

The original partial view is supposed to be replaced with at new version of `<div id="page13">`.

What is actually happening is the new version of `<div id="page13">` is being inserted after the old one.

How can I replace the page with the new one?

**View**

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page13">
<div data-role="content">
    <div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ReinstateAlarms", "Mobile", new { EntityId = ViewBag.EntityId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "page13", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <label for="">Reinstate Alarms</label>
        <button type="submit" value="Search" >Submit</button>
    }
    </div>
<div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer-div" class="footer-div" >
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1" data-transition="fade" data-icon="home">Final Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page4" data-transition="fade" data-icon="grid">Panel</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Actual Form Tag**

```
<form action="/m/ReinstateAlarms/9665" data-ajax="true" &#39;slideup&#39;, true, false);" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#page13" id="form1" method="post">
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult PanelAlarms(string EntityId)
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Mobile/Partial/PanelAlarms.cshtml");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ReinstateAlarms(string EntityId)
    {
        //Do some databse stufff
        return PanelAlarms(EntityId);
    }
```

Comment: what you could do is, wrap the form in a `div` and make another "new view"`div` and `.hide()` it. Once the form is submitted, `.hide()` the form and `.show()` the new view div.

Comment: I thought about that, or using a container div inside `<div data-role="content">` and replacing that. I hoping to find a cleaner solution since I'll be doing this in many different places.

Comment: Either way, you need to append new markup into #page13 or .`load()` page into it. i'll give you two examples.

Comment: [Check this jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/NQTq7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I accomplished submitting the form and refreshing the page with and updated version.

I used a regular`<form>`, rather then the Ajax.BeginForm(). The data-ajax must be set to false.

**Form**

```
<form id="meterForm" data-ajax="false">
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <label for="MeterReadingHours">Update Meter Reading</label><br />
      <input type="number" aria-valuemin="1" aria-required="true" name="MeterReadingHours" />
      <button type="submit" value="Update" >Update</button>
</form>
```

Then use jquery to bind a function to submitting the form. `e.preventDefault();`prevents the form from being submitted. Set up a regular [$.post() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to submit the form. Then in the response, use [$().load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) get a new version of the `<div data-role="content">` from whatever ActionResult created the original one. load() allowed you specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. Here we only need the content div, so we specify `div[data-role="content"]` after the URL.

If you stop here, and run the script everything will work - but the new content div will be displayed as plain text without the jquery styles applied. To force the update, pass the function `$('#page15').trigger('create');` into the complete attribute of .load(). This will cause the newly inserted elements to be initialized by jQuery.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#meterUpdateForm').bind('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(
        '@Url.Action("MeterReadingUpdate", "Mobile", new { EntityId = ViewBag.EntityId })',
        $(this).serialize(),
        function (response) {
            $('#page15 div[data-role="content"]').load(
                 '@Url.Action("MeterReading", "Mobile", new { EntityId = ViewBag.EntityId }) div[data-role="content"]', 
                 function () {
                     $('#page15').trigger('create');
                 });
             });
         });
     });
 });
```